# replacing "<" with "<b>" and ">" with "</b>"

Tags: c#, string, replace

```
string x = "I am a hunter, what do i do. <Name> is a good boy. His age is <Age> and a <occupation> of <Institute>. \n\n He is passionate about his <passion> and also a hardworking fellow. <WifeName> is his wife and she is a sweet girl, She loves her husband a lot. Her age is <WifeAge> and <occupation> of <Institute>";
```

This text dosen't mean anything. but what i have to do is to replace all "`<`" with "`<b>`" and all "`>`"  with  "`</b>`", all "`\n\n`" with "`<br/>`".

I tried to use :

```
string y = replace(replace(x,"<","<b>"),">","</b>");
```

this led me to a devastating result. I think you all can guess, what happened. Now I am searching for a easy and simple solution for this replacement. I wish, I could make this clear.

Comment: you may try regex to do it

Comment: can you show the sample output?

Comment: I'd do something like this in Javascript: `x.replace(/\</g, '<b').replace(/\>/g, '</b>').replace(/<b/g, '<b>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you use "`<`" to denote "Start bold" and "`>`" to denote "End bold".

Using a composite call to `String.Replace` obviously isn't going to work because `<` is used in the replacement token which is matched by the next call.

One approach is to do the replacement as you encounter it and write it to a new string, like so:

```
String input = "I am a hunter, what do i do...";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(Char c in input) {

    switch(c) {
        case '<':
            sb.Append("<b>");
            break;
        case '>':
            sb.Append("</b>");
            break;
        case '\r':
            break; // ignore \r characters.
        case '\n':
            sb.Append("<br />");
            break;
        default:
            sb.Append( c );
            break;
    } 
}
return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks. It's easy and simple to understand. And worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested this gets be done best with regex.

Try something like this:

```
string x = "I am a hunter, what do i do. <Name> is a good boy. His age is <Age> and a <occupation> of <Institute>. \n\n He is passionate about his <passion> and also a hardworking fellow. <WifeName> is his wife and she is a sweet girl, She loves her husband a lot. Her age is <WifeAge> and <occupation> of <Institute>";
var y = Regex.Replace(x, "<(?<match>[^>.]*)>", "<b>${match}</b>");
```

What the regex do is to match all characters excpect > which are located in between < and > and replaces it. The groupname is called "match" but you can rename it of course.

Answer (score 0):

try this code snippet,

```
string x = "I am a hunter, what do i do. <Name> is a good boy......";
string _val = x.Replace("<", "<b>");
_val = Regex.Replace(_val, "(?<!<b)>", "</b>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.

```
String y = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(x, "<", "{b}"), ">", "{/b}"), "}", ">"), "{", "<");
```

First change `<` into `{b}` then change `>` into `{/b}`

Finally, convert `{}` to `<>`

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a pseudo UBB format. Instead of a square bracket, you used the greater/less-than symbols.

I suggest using regex
here's a rough code:

```
var rgEx = new Regex("<(.+?)>");
string convertedString = rgEx.Replace("Hello is it <me> you're looking for?", "<b>$1</b>");
```

the problem with this is it may convert some html codes you render from code. I would suggest using the standard UBB format to avoid future problems

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your replacement values contain tokens from the original characters that are being replaced. What you need to do is use an interim token that is unlikely to be found within your original text.

```
var replacementList = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>()
{
    Tuple.Create("<", "#OPENINGTOKEN#", "<b>"),
    Tuple.Create(">", "#CLOSINGTOKEN#", "</b>")
};

string x = "I am a hunter, what do i do. <Name> is a good boy.";

foreach (var tokenTriple in replacementList)
{
    x = x.Replace(tokenTriple.Item1, tokenTriple.Item2);
}

foreach (var tokenTriple in replacementList)
{
    x = x.Replace(tokenTriple.Item2, tokenTriple.Item3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it.

```
// find words and whitespace between < and > 
String matchpattern = @"\<([\w\s]+)\>";  
// wrap them between <b> and </b> tags.
String replacementpattern = @"<b>$1</b>";
x = Regex.Replace(x,matchpattern,replacementpattern));
```